# Prototype.js - cannot see added headers in request details in browser

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs, request-headers

I would like to add some headers to Ajax.Request. I created requestHeader object:

```
requestHeaders: {
     'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
     'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS',
     'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
}
```

but cannot see those headers in my request (checking in browser). In console I see the error:

"XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://my_domain.com?some_parameters. Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers."

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this [github Pull Request](https://github.com/victor-homyakov/prototype/commit/2811f40a464b69274f407a3e39ce0e08584f39bd%20here) with the latest version (1.7.2) you should be able to remove the extra `X-*` headers that Prototype adds to Ajax requests.

I think that will fix the problem you are having as there are 2 headers that cause problems with CORS requests, `X-Requested-With` and `X-Prototype-Version`

so using your same headers object

```
requestHeaders: {
 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS',
 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
 'X-Requested-With': null,
 'X-Prototype-Version': null
}
```